# Site is down after migrating to Cloudflare

Tags: azure, dns, cdn, cloudflare, cname

I wanted to use CloudFlare for my website (hosted on Microsoft Azure).

I have added my domain to Cloudflare, and changed my domains nameservers to the ones I got from Cloudflare.

Furthermore, cloudflare imported my current DNS settings which are the following (my domain has been replaced with domain.com):

[image]

I thought the migration would go smoothly, however, when I go to www.domain.com I get the error:

> The webpage at http://www.domain.com/ might be temporarily down or
>   it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

However, when I refresh a couple of times it finally loads the site.
If I go to domain.com (no www-prefix), I get the error:

> domain.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

What could be going on?

Comment: Can you share the real domain name?

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue...if you are seeing inconsistent responses from your Azure Website, they you should raise an Azure support ticket.

For the second issue...try verifying the CLOUDFLARE DNS resolution via http://digwebinterface.com, both via a recursive DNS service and by querying against the CLOUDFLARE name servers directly.  If the latter is working, there must be a problem in your DNS delegation (check name server settings with your registrar, try also a delegation validation service such as http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/).  If the latter is not working, you'll need to take it up with CLOUDFLARE.

Answer (score 0):

You need both @ and www CNAME specified in your host records. Not just www.

the refresh is normal after you make a dns change. The browser keeps the dns lookup in cache, so if you visit the site on another browser you won't have to do a refresh. Just clear your browser cache when you want to see dns changes, but some edits could take 15min or longer to see changes.